# cocoa : use of calayer is crashing my application in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I am using the following code to set the background color of my nsview using calayer.

```
    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [self.view setLayer:viewLayer];
    [self.view setWantsLayer:YES]; 
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.74, 0.99, 0.79, 1.0)];
```

This code is crashing my application.

Please help me..

Comment: When and where do you call this code?

Comment: during application initialization time.

Comment: sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: actually i have to set the color of my view as light green color. and it is only possible with calayer .  if is there any other way to set the background color of my view . please help me out.

Comment: When does your "application initialization time" start? Are your sure that your view has loaded by this moment? Another way to set the background color is subclass `NSView` and overwrite `-drawRect` method

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. The only thing that you must check is your view has loaded by that time you set the layer for it.

If you just want to draw the view with specified background color you don't have to set the CALayer for it. The easiest way is make your own `NSView` subclass:

```
@interface MyColoredView: NSView

@property (copy) NSColor* backgroundColor;

@end

@implementation MyColoredView

@synthetize backgroundColor;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [self.backgroundColor set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
}

@end
```

After that you must set the class for your view in IB to `MyColoredView` and set it's background color during initialization:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [NSColor greenColor];
```